# Using MaTeX after plotting

Tags: plotting, plot-themes, matex

I have plotted something using `Mathematica 11.0` and it takes a while to generate the plot.

I would like to use the package `MaTeX` on the generated plot to do some modifications but it seems that I will have to re-plot everytime I need to do any modification. Is there any way to use the package to modify the plot after obtaining it instead of during the pre-compile-time of the plot (so to speak)?

Here is the code I am using :

```
Plot[2.0*solk[logn], {logn, 0, 23}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Log\), \(10\)]\)[n]", 
   "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Log\), \(10\)]\)[\*
StyleBox[\"\[CapitalLambda]\",\nFontSize->16]]\), \(2\)]\)"}, 
 PlotRange -> Full, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 700, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[MaTeX["{ Number~ of~ Entangled~ Spins~ (N) }"], 
    FontSize -> 35], 
   Style[MaTeX[
     "{ Cosmological~constant~ in~ static~ patch}~ (\\Lambda)"], 
    FontSize -> 35]}, 
 LabelStyle -> {Directive[Black, Bold], FontSize -> 15}]
```

Comment: Can you be specific about what kind of modification you want to make? BTW there are several mistakes in how you use MaTeX: it expects math-mode LaTeX. If you want text, use `\text`. `Style` cannot be applied to the output.

Comment: @Szabolcs Modifications like trying various font-sizes, colours etc on the labels. If possible, even change the `ImageSize`. Whatever is available to be modified post plot production I would like to modify. Thanks for the tip on the math-mode expectation. I received this from a collaborator and now I can make it look better. Can you please point out other mistakes as well?

Comment: You can change any `Graphics` option using `Show`, including ImageSize, FrameLabels, PlotLabel, etc., even Epilog.  `Show[plot, opt1 -> val1, ...]`. No need to regenerate the plot.